# Why can't I see Ubuntu in my EFI list?

Tags: boot, uefi, usb-installation

I followed the instructions at https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#3 and got the "installation successful" message, but when I restarted my machine, I didn't find any new boot options in the EFI list. Sorry, I can't include a screenshot, but I don't know how to take 2MB pictures on my phone.

Comment: To address photo issue: Take a regular 4  - 6 MB picture on your phone. Then open it with GIMP and export it as .jpg with reduced quality percentage, try 80% to make it 2 MB or less. To address EFI issue, try boot-repair from Live USB: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I've been following the steps in the boot repair link you posted, but it's become stuck at "create a BootInfo summary." Should I just stop it and start again?

Comment: Never mind. It seems that the boot info summary isn't required. Boot repair seems to have done the trick regardless. Thanks WinEunuuchs2Unix.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to WinEunuuchs2Unix for your comment. Boot-repair seems to have done the trick.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair